# How to Insert default into not null column if value is null in Maria db

Tags: insert, mariadb, default, notnull

I have below table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1(
    id int AutoIncrement PRIMARY KEY,
    message varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA'
)
```

I run the below query:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, message) VALUES (null, null);
```

It gives me Error:

```
Error Code: 1048. Column 'message' cannot be null
```

I want the below result with the same insert query.

### Output

```
|id | message|
|1  | NA     |
```

Are there any MySQL settings?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is at first sight tricky, because conceptually you want to an insert without specifying a primary key value *or* a message, instead relying entirely on MySQL to provide the default values.

To insert an empty row, just specify the primary key column along with a single `NULL` for the `VALUES`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1(
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA'
);

INSERT INTO Table_1 (id) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM Table_1;
```

**Output:**

```
   id | message
1  1  | NA
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I want the 'message' column in the insert list like INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, message ) VALUES (NULL, NULL);

Comment: @SAM If you want to do this, then use my answer.  If you have _other_ columns, then let us know what they are and the answer can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax error this will work.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message varchar(64) DEFAULT 'NA',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If you want to add value `Null` you should not add this constrains in your table stucture then.

Comment: This is not what was asked. The other answer is correct.